# Stored procedure :GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a stored procedure. @Sea is output parameter from the user. In Inline query it is executing but in stored procedure not getting below error.

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[procedure name]
(
    @APTSeason NVARCHAR(1000),
    @rptsummary NVARCHAR(1000),
    @Sea NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT (@Sea),
        Sum(ProjectedRevenue) as 'Total_$',
        Sum(TotalSalesUnits) as 'Total_U',


    From  table name

    group by @Sea
END
Go
```

Error:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference

Comment: What's the point of @Sea? It seems like the query would be exactly the same without the group by (it would just return one row, with the same data, either way), so you could just get rid of the group by?

Comment: i have been used @Sea in select list so i need use group by

Comment: What happens if you remove the parentheses from around the first (@Sea)?

Comment: I tried  by removing also no change same error

Comment: There is no need for using group by, Remove `group by @Sea` and keep `SELECT (@Sea),` as it , and try again.

Comment: I Tried but doesn't work out .If you are using aggregate , you need to use group by clause its showing

Comment: This may help: http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/SQL/Each-GROUP-BY-expression-must-contain-at-least-one-column-that-is-not-an-outer-reference.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `Dynamic SQL`:

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[procedure name]
(
    @APTSeason NVARCHAR(1000),
    @rptsummary NVARCHAR(1000),
    @Sea NVARCHAR(1000)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT (' + QUOTENAME(@Sea) +'),
        Sum(ProjectedRevenue) as ''Total_$'',
        Sum(TotalSalesUnits) as ''Total_U'',


    From  table name

    group by ' + QUOTENAME(@Sea)

PRINT(@SQL)
--EXEC(@SQL)  --Comment this in if the previous "Print" outputs the correct SQL
END
Go
```

PS: I do not see the `@APTSeason` and `@rptsummary` are necessary here if they are not used anywhere in the SP.

Answer (score 0):

--GROUP BY CLAUSE SHOULD INCLUDE COLUMNS FROM THE SELECT QUERY WITHOUT ANY LITERALS OR CONSTANTS.

You can try the below steps to do a work around:

1. Give @set an alias name with the as clause.
2. Remove the group by clause having @set.

It will give the result without an error.